# PYTHON: getting all values in a dict inside a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

I have a list of dictionaries and i want to get the values by using the keys.

I have this list as a headers:

```
headers = ['color','age','name']
```

And this list of dictionaries as contents:

```
contents =[{'name':'bryan','age':'4','color':'white'},{'age':'3','name':'gordon'},{'name':'jordan','color':'black','age':'2'}]
```

and i have this code to get all the values in it using the headers

```
res = [list(itemgetter(*headers)(i)) for i in contents]
```

But I am getting an

> `ErrorKey: 'color'`

because there's no key ("color" - based from the headers) in the dictionary.

Now i am confused, Can someone help me figure out on how to "not to get an error" when running my code.

Comment: the 2nd entry in your list doesn't have `color`, you can check that a key exists before getting it `if name in mydict` or you can set a default value `mydict.get(name, None)` or probably other options too!

Comment: `itemgetter()` unfortunately doesn't have an option to specify a default value when the key is missing.  You'd have to do something like `[[dct.get(key, None) for key in headers] for dct in contents]` - change `None` to whatever value you want for missing keys, an empty string might be more appropriate for you.

Comment: thanks @jasonharper this works perfectly. Thank you for the idea!!

Comment: If you don't want the `Nones` and still want a one-liner, you can actually stick with `itemgetter`, see my edit

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
[dic.get(key) for key in headers for dic in contents]
```

Result:

```
['white', None, 'black', '4', '3', '2', 'bryan', 'gordon', 'jordan']
```

If you don't want the `Nones`, a slight modification on your version using set intersection:

```
[list(itemgetter(*set(headers) & dic.keys())(dic)) for dic in contents]
```

Result:

```
 [['white', 'bryan', '4'], ['gordon', '3'], ['2', 'jordan', 'black']]
```

If you use the second variation, you probably want the headers as a set in advance to avoid reapplying:

```
headers = set(headers)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use your headers as a set and then unpack for `itemgetter` parameters the intersection between your heders and the keys from your actual dictionary:

```
headers = {'color','age','name'}
contents =[{'name':'bryan','age':'4','color':'white'},{'age':'3','name':'gordon'},{'name':'jordan','color':'black','age':'2'}]

res = [list(itemgetter(*headers.intersection(i))(i)) for i in contents]
# [['bryan', '4', 'white'], ['gordon', '3'], ['jordan', '2', 'black']]
```

or you can use a list comprehension:

```
res = [[d[h] for h in headers if h in d] for d in contents]
# [['bryan', '4', 'white'], ['gordon', '3'], ['jordan', '2', 'black']]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Here is how you can do that with a nested list comprehension:**

```
headers = ['color','age','name']

contents =[{'name':'bryan','age':'4','color':'white'},{'age':'3','name':'gordon'},{'name':'jordan','color':'black','age':'2'}]

res = [list(i.get(d) for d in headers) for i in contents]

print(res)
```

Output:

```
[['white', '4', 'bryan'], [None, '3', 'gordon'], ['black', '2', 'jordan']]
```

**If you want to omit the `None`s:**

```
res = [list(i.get(d) for d in headers if i.get(d) != None) for i in contents]
```

Output:

```
[['white', '4', 'bryan'], ['3', 'gordon'], ['black', '2', 'jordan']]
```